# How to remember the user ID across all sites using django and sql?

Tags: sql, django, sessionid

I am creating an online shop using DJANGO and SQL (I connect to the DB via pyodbc, it is working properly).

This is meant to be for an experiment. I assign the participant ID when he or she starts the website. How can I remember that participant ID across the whole application?

Comment: Use Sessions and make sure you dispose the session at the end.

Answer (score 0):

As @Justin Russo stated, [Sessions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/http/sessions/) and a [middleware](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/http/middleware/) to set the session are really your only option here.

Because you never know what url pattern / view someone will arrive at your application via, I would get/set this session in a middleware, which can do whatever processing you need on *every* request, regardless of the url.

```
# settings.py
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'some_app_module.middleware.UserSession',
)

class UserSession(object):
    def process_request(self, request):
        x_forwarded_for = request.META.get('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR')
        if x_forwarded_for:
            ip = x_forwarded_for.split(',')[0]
        else:
            ip = request.META.get('REMOTE_ADDR')

        request['user_session'] = request.session.get(ip, ip)
        return request
```